# Codeigniter: Query result without repetition for a field

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this query in my model:

```
public function getById(int $id): ?array
    {
        $query = $this->db->select(['id', 'docent_id', 'date', 'start_at', 'end_at'])
                ->where('docent_id', $id)
                ->where('delete_date is null')
                ->get('Agenda');
        $res = $query->result();

        return $res;
    }
```

My problem is in my DB I have something like:

```
| id | docent_id | date       | start_at | end_at
| 1  |    1      | 2020-05-04 |   09:00  | 10:00
| 2  |    1      | 2020-05-04 |   10:00  | 11:00
```

So this result prints me for the same docent_id two fields. I would to group the answer so that the date is not repeated twice, so that it gives me a single result for the same for the same docent, with the same date and separate start and end times.

How can I do? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is `GROUP BY`. The query below will show the data only when the combination of the all 4(`docent_id`, `date`, `start_at` and `end_at`) is different. See if this helps you.

```
$query = $this->db->select(['id', 'docent_id', 'date', 'start_at', 'end_at'])
                  ->where('docent_id', $id)
                  ->where('delete_date is null')
                  ->group_by(array("docent_id", "date", "start_at", "end_at"))
                  ->get('Agenda');

$res = $query->result();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have tried this but it' gives me only the first result, so this one: ` 2020-05-04 |   09:00  | 10:00 `

Comment: Isn't that what you want? As you wrote -`So this result prints me for the same docent_id two fields. I would to group the answer so that the date is not repeated twice, so that it gives me a single result for the same for the same docent, with the same date and separate start and end times.` What does it mean then?

Comment: I mean that they have the same date filed but different start and end hours. I would not show the same date field twice but one date and the different hours

Comment: Hey @Jack23, I have updated the answer, see if this one helps you.